# Event emitter's parameter is undefined for listener

Tags: angular

In Angular2 component I use EventEmitter to emit an event with parameter. In the parent component listener this parameter is undefined. Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vk1rKNsKGiqVaHHBRKMk?p=preview):

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Output} from 'angular2/core'
@Component({
  template: `<ul>
  <li *ngFor="#product of products" (click)="onClick(product)">{{product.name}}</li>
  </ul>`,
  selector: 'product-picker',
  outputs: ['pick']
})
export class ProductPicker {
  products: Array<any>;
  pick: EventEmitter<any>;
  constructor() {
    this.products = [
      {id: 1, name: 'first product'},
      {id: 2, name: 'second product'},
      {id: 3, name: 'third product'},
      ];
    this.pick = new EventEmitter();
  }
  onClick(product) {
    this.pick.emit(product);
  }
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Pick a product</h2>
      <product-picker (pick)="onPick(item)"></product-picker>
    </div>
    <div>You picked: {{name}}</div>
  `,
  directives: [ProductPicker]
})
export class App {
  name: string = 'nothing';
  onPick(item) {
    if (typeof item == 'undefined') {
      console.log("item is undefined!");
    } else {
      this.name = item.name;
    }
  }
}
```

How to pass the picked product to parent component?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should $event like this:

```
<product-picker (pick)="onPick($event)"></product-picker>
```

It corresponds to the value you provided when telling the emit method of the associated EventEmitter.

In your case the item variable provided as parameter corresponds to nothing.

Comment: This works, thanks. It's not clear for me why this is correct, then: `(click)="onClick(product)`. Here the parameter is a variable name, not $event, but is value is visible to listener (passing $event would be useless here). I mean, when it is necessary to use the word "$event" as parameter and when another name can be used?

Comment: @camcam, when we bind to a custom event on a component, `$event` is the special keyword that we must use to get the value that was `emit()`ted.  When we bind to a DOM event, like `click`, `$event` is the DOM event.  For either type of binding, we also have access to local template variables, hence the reason we can also use `product`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Thierry Templier, I had the same issue, but it is resolved when I used $event in the parent component template <ion-content padding>
    <div *ngFor="let lesson of getSelectedSeriesLessons()">
        <lesson-component [track]="lesson" (updateMediaPlayerEvent)="onUpdateMediaPlayerLesson($event)"></lesson-component>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="playingLesson != null">
        <lesson-component [track]="playingLesson"></lesson-component>
    </div>
</ion-content>

Comment: Not working in my case.Listener:
<app-game-control (gameRunning)="alocateNumbers($event)"></app-game-control>
sender:
this.intervalOperation = setInterval(() => {
     console.log(this.number);
      this.number++;
      this.gameRunning.emit({number: this.number});
    }, 1000);